# Component 'xyz' has an invalid value for property 'Select Model'

Tags: visualforce, lightning

I am developing a 'configurable' component, where a user can select their Model from a dropdown (developed in the .design of the bundle), but I get the following error when I click "Save" on the AppBuilder:

```
Component 'xyz' has an invalid value for property 'Select Model'.
```

The thing is, in the .cmp, the attribute gets set from the dropdown, and I can't figure out where the problem arises from. Here's my code:

.cmp

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
     <aura:attribute name="selectedModelId" type="String" access="global"/>
{!v.selectedModelId}
</aura:component>
```

.design

```
<design:component >
    <design:attribute name="selectedModelId" label="Select Model" datasource="apex://VisionModels"/>
</design:component>
```

Here's a screenshot as a proof that the component attribute gets set from the dropdown, since it gets printed when I select an option.

[image: Photo]

Thank you.

Comment: What happens when you change the datasource to a static list of values. I have not seen anyone use apex://VisionModels (assuming this is some kinda vf page?)

Comment: It's a controller that will feed the data dynamically. Kind of what they have in the documentation. Let me try with static values and I'll come back.

Comment: I assume this is the doc: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_forcecom_lab_dynamic_picklists.htm can you post your apex class that populates this picklist for the datasource?

Comment: I feel you should not pass the label for the design:attribute since your VisualEditor.DataRow takes in label/value for the datasource. Though I am not sure if the label represents the label for design:attribute or the label for the picklist. Anyway try by not passing the label for the design attribute and see what happens also. You can always use a outputlable to populate the select model text in case if this is what is messing up the save https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_VisualEditor_DataRow.htm

Comment: Thanks all for the help. I found out the actual reason, and it was completely something else. I actually had loaded up these values from an api call, and apparently you can't make DML statements after a callout. That means, when the system tries to save the component setting, it fails and throws an error.